# Best practices to avoid CookieTheftException in case of Spring Remember me?

Tags: java, exception, cookies, spring-security, remember-me

I'm new at spring security, and I've implemented the `remember me` function for my application.

While I was testing my application, I got `CookieTheftException` few times. I've read few discusson about this, and done the following configuration:

```
web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**");
```

I have still concern about this, and I'm afraid that I will still get this exception. I want make sure that that this won't happen in the future and won't cause me headache.

I would really appropriate if you could share your experiences/knowledge about this.

Thanks!